# How to install firefox developer edition?

Tags: firefox, browser

I downloaded firefox developer edition and extracted it from tar.bz2, tryid to install it by running this `./firefox` command but it opens it only temporarily but I wnat to install it to my computer. I use Linux Mint 17 cinnamon

Comment: This Q/A on Ask Ubuntu might be of help - How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?: http://askubuntu.com/q/548003/36315

Answer (score 1):

Download it from here - https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

Save the folder somewhere and open the file called "firefox" (the one next to firefox-bin)

Answer (score 1):

As a linux Mint user this is the most effective method I have found. It allows me to keep stock Firefox separate from developer.

Download from here https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

Extract and move.

```
$ tar xjf firefox-45.0a2.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
$ sudo mv firefox /usr/local/firefox_dev
```

Create a desktop entry at `~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop`
 OR
on some distros here `/usr/share/applications/...`
Formatted Like...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/usr/local/firefox_dev/firefox
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/local/firefox_dev/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
```

Should show up in the app panel promptly.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded my firefox to firefox-developer using the steps below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox/trusty
```

Comment: `E: Release 'trusty' for 'firefox' was not found`

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora 23, you can intall firefox developer edition, run it like so:

```
curl -L http://git.io/firefoxdev | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisites**

1 File manager nautilus, nemo etc

2  gnome-panel

**Steps**

1. Download the firefox developer edition here:
   https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/
2. Open nautilus file manager in sudo mode by using following command

   *sudo nautilus*
3. Make Folder firefox-developer inside /opt to save extracted files

   a. Using command line

   *sudo mkdir /opt/firefox-developer*

   b. Using GUI
4. Extract the tar file and add firefox folder to /opt/firefox-developer/

   a. Using command line

   *cd /opt/firefox-developer*

   *tar xvjf  path_of_tar_file*

   b. Using archieve manager
5. Change permission for /opt/firefox-developer folder

   a. Using terminal

   *sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/firefox-developer*

> we are using -R for repetitive changing because we have to change
>   permissions for contents inside folders also.

7. Open /opt/firefox-developer/firefox  using nautilus file manager

   a. Select file named firefox
   b. Open Properties>>Permissions tab >> Allow Executing file as program >> Close
8. Open Nautilus:

   a. Click on files icon at upper-left corner of screen >> Preferences >> Behaviour tab

   b. click on “Run executable text files when they are opened”
9. Open terminal because we have to create launcher for opening application:

   gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications --create-new
10. new dialog-box will be appeared

    a. Name>> Give any suitable name for shortcut e.g. Firefox-Developer

    b. Command>> Click on Browse and select path of /opt/firefox-developer/firefox/firefox file

    c. Comment>> Add suitable comment for more-info about application

    d. icon>> Click on icon at left side box and select your custom icon.

Answer (score -1):

The Firefox Developer Edition is available as part of Ubuntu Make:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

After that just run the Firefox installer without sudo (Choose installation path then language and it's Done ):

```
umake web firefox-dev
```

Comment: ERROR: Unhandled exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 158, in wrapper
    function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/frameworks/web.py", line 116, in get_metadata_and_check_license
    UI.delayed_display(TextWithChoices(_("Choose language: {}".format(default_label)), languages, True))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/interactions/__init__.py", line 59, in __init__
    raise BaseException(message)

Comment: Works if you do this: `umake web firefox-dev --lang en-US`